# One link instead of two for \citep{} in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I'm writing some LaTeX for a document, and I'm using natbib for my citations, with the command \citep{ref}.

However, \citep is producing something like that (Author et al., Year), but 'Author et al.' and 'Year' are two separated links (pointing to the same reference).
I would like this to be only one link 'Author et al.,Year'.

How could I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you make a [mre]? Also what should happen for contracted citation likes "Mickey Mouse 2000 & 2008"? To which of the two references should this link?

Comment: Nevermind, it's a duplicate of that post, I don't know why I didn't find it in my previous researches: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24136/natbib-and-hyperref-for-author-year-style-produces-two-links

Answer (score 1):

Found this answer here:

[natbib and hyperref for (Author, Year) style produces two links](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24136/natbib-and-hyperref-for-author-year-style-produces-two-links)

Which consists in adding to the preambule:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\hyper@natlinkbreak[2]{#1}
\makeatother
```